# NServiceBus Could not load file or assembly

Tags: nservicebus

I am getting the below error when i call "NServiceBus.Host.exe". The issue appears to be itextsharp.dll. I've read that i can use

"Configure.With(AllAssemblies.Except("itextsharp.dll"))... // rest of your config"

But i'm using the following sample and not sure where to add this property.

[http://docs.particular.net/samples/web/asp-mvc-application/](http://www.nservicebus.com/docs/Samples/AsyncPages.aspx)

#

Unhandled Exception: Magnum.StateMachine.StateMachineException: Exception occurr
ed in Topshelf.Internal.ServiceController`1[[NServiceBus.Host.Internal.GenericHo
st, NServiceBus.Host, Version=2.6.0.1504, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9fc386
479f8a226c]] during state Initial while handling OnStart ---> System.Exception:
Exception when starting endpoint, error has been logged. Reason: Could not load
file or assembly 'file:///D:\dev\MYSITE\MYSITE.EStore\EStore.Server\bin\Debug\itexts
harp.dll' or one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception fro
m HRESULT: 0x80131515)
   at NServiceBus.Host.Internal.GenericHost.Start() in d:\BuildAgent-02\work\20b
5f701adefe8f8\src\host\NServiceBus.Host\Internal\GenericHost.cs:line 90
   at Magnum.StateMachine.EventActionList`1.Execute(T stateMachine, Event event,
 Object parameter) in :line 0
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Server stack trace:
   at Magnum.StateMachine.ExceptionActionDictionary`1.HandleException(T stateMac
hine, Event event, Object parameter, Exception exception) in :line 0
   at Magnum.StateMachine.EventActionList`1.Execute(T stateMachine, Event event,
 Object parameter) in :line 0
   at Magnum.StateMachine.State`1.RaiseEvent(T instance, BasicEvent`1 eevent, Ob
ject value) in :line 0
   at Magnum.StateMachine.StateMachine`1.RaiseEvent(Event raised) in :line 0
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(
IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean fExecuteInCont
ext, Object[]& outArgs)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMes
sage msg, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean fExecuteInContext)

Exception rethrown at [0]:
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage req
Msg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgDa
ta, Int32 type)
   at Topshelf.Internal.ServiceControllerProxy.Start()
   at Topshelf.Internal.ServiceCoordinator.Start() in d:\dev\open-source\topshel
f\src\Topshelf\Internal\ServiceCoordinator.cs:line 54
   at Topshelf.Internal.Hosts.ConsoleHost.Run() in d:\dev\open-source\topshelf\s
rc\Topshelf\Internal\Hosts\ConsoleHost.cs:line 53
   at NServiceBus.Host.Program.Main(String[] args) in d:\BuildAgent-02\work\20b5
f701adefe8f8\src\host\NServiceBus.Host\Program.cs:line 103

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When NserviceBus host starts it tries to retrieve all types from assemblies you specify.
In the sample you provide it uses NServiceBus.Configure.WithWeb() method.
This is the same as to call NServiceBus.Configure.With(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DynamicDirectory)

You get the excpetion because "itextsharp.dll" cannot be loaded to AppDomain (this is done by calling Assembly.LoadFrom(file.FullName) method).

To fix the issue, you may manually specify assemblies you need to scan by using one of NServiceBus.Configure.With() overloads.